# Download Files and Open them in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, download

I am wondering what's the best way to handle downloading multiple files at once in (byte array). I am downloading files from the server in one single GET call and I was wondering how do split up the files since it's one giant stream of data? How then can I determine and sort the files to show only ones I can open by a tableview of the filename?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: If you could share some of the code we might be able to help in a better way.
I am not sure if I can answer the question with this much detail.

Comment: @user2421700 I don't have any code besides for the downloading the byte array. I don't know what to do with the byte data.